# iOS Simulator - Safari forcing WWW on URLs

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, xcode-simulator

When trying to use Safari on iOS Simulator (I'm running on the latest Yosemite build with about a 2011-ish iMac), WWW is automatically prepended to my urls. I'm trying to debug a site I'm working on through the ngrok tunnel service and I can only access the url without www...any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

www is *only* prepended in iOS if the URL *without* www fails without any response from the server. Double-check that everything is functioning correctly and you should be fine.

Comment: I just experienced an issue, where the 'www' was also appended, when the server responded with HTTP status `401` -- Safari moved to a different URL and the expected authentication dialog was never shown.